# "Breakpoint will not currently be hit. Breakpoint set but not yet bound" in cshtml of a MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, breakpoints

While debugging cshtml in my MVC project the debugger doesn't hits. It says "Breakpoint will not currently be hit. Breakpoint set but not yet bound". I tried couple of options-

1. Deleting bin, obj, .vs, cleaning solution and then building it.
2. Tried couple of options on Debug -> Options -> Debugging(General)- Like unchecking 'Just my Code' etc.
3. Tried updating the properties of project.

But none of these worked. Its really driving me crazy, any inputs on this would be a great help.

Comment: Is it just this specific cshtml file or all cshtml files? If it's all of them, is it just cshtml files, or is it effecting your entire codebase? Also it might seem silly, but if you're using Visual Studio try closing all instances of Visual studio (Even unrelated ones) and reopening just the 1 project and debugging then.

Comment: @Lolop- The breakpoint is hitting on the .cs files of this project. But, its not working for any of the cshtml files. Moreover, the strange thing is that it works for cshtml files in other project of the same solution. Though, while I deleted the bin, obj folders etc I did try closing, reopening and rebuilding it but it didn't work. Let me try killing the process as well and see if it works.

Comment: I mentioned closing all VS instances because in a previous project of mine, if I ever accidentally opened the same solution in a different VS instance, then close it, it seemingly 'took over' even though I closed it. None of my breakpoints in the original instance would ever get hit, but seeing as you're getting a mix of some breakpoints hitting and some not, I think it's unrelated.

Comment: Last thing I could think of is maybe the SDK of the project? Dunno if it'd related to a .Net Framework project (If that's what you're using), but with .Net Core, it has to be `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` or `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` for the cshtml pages to be compiled. Bit of a long shot as that would have been unlikely to change in your project, but I'm not super familiar with MVC sorry. Hopefully someone with more experience can chime in at some point.

Comment: @Lolop- The reference to System.Web and System.Web.Razor is already there in the project. So I don't think that should be an issue. But thanks for your prompt response.